# Automatically send Ether only when received?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, receive

How would I go about creating a smart contract that when the current wallet receives Eth. It would instantly be sent to a different specified address. I have experimented with the receive() function but I am struggling to understand it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SendEth {
    //Receive event
    event Receive(address, uint);
    receive () external payable {
        emit Receive(msg.sender, msg.value);
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point of receive the contract will already be the owner of the eth. So if you would like to transfer to another address on every receive just use the `transfer` method:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SendEth {
    address payable beneficiary = "ox...";

    //Receive event
    event Receive(address, uint);
    receive () external payable {
        emit Receive(msg.sender, msg.value);
        uint balance = msg.value;
        beneficiary.transfer(balance);//transfer deposited amount to fixed address
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that there are ways to go around this. E.g. when a contract is suicided it can send ETH as part of the operation and it will not trigger the `receive` or `fallback` method.

Comment: See https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#forcibly-sending-ether-to-a-contract